# Count the Quantity field based on a parameter

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Hopefully you can help, I have a spreadsheet that has 3 columns, qty, item & type, The qty cells are updated by a formula and I am trying to see what the quantity is of any type so it would be combining the value of each qty cell of the same type and I can't seem to get it to work. Below is a screenshot of the sheet.

[image: cell view]

and this is how simply i want the output to be
[image: output]

Comment: can you mock up what your output would look like also and put that in your question ?

Comment: Try this in L1 and fill down: `=SUMIF(I$2:I$8,K1,G$2:G$8)`.

Comment: looks like it did thanks! If you put it as an answer I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SUMIF()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function) is what you need here.

Type this in L1 and fill down: `=SUMIF(I$2:I$8,K1,G$2:G$8)`

This formula looks in I2:I8 for K1 (Car) and sums the corresponding numbers from Column G.

Glad to help.